# How to clean up mongoose validation errors

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoose for validation, and I want to pass the results back to the client. The JSON blob that mongoose gives for errors is almost exactly what I need, but it has some extra stuff:

```
errors: 
 { username: 
    { [ValidatorError: Path `username` is required.]
      properties: [Object],
      message: 'Path `username` is required.',
      name: 'ValidatorError',
      kind: 'required',
      path: 'username',
      value: undefined } } }
```

The `username.properties` field is unecessary for the client. I know I can do `delete username.properties`, but is there a nicer way to clean up the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `lodash` library

```
var _ = require('lodash');

yourMongooseError = _.mapValues(yourMongooseError, function(field) {
  return _.omit(field, ['properties']); // add any other props that you want to remove from each field
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`Object.entries(err.errors).map((error: any) => error[1].message).join()`

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.